# My frontend javascript file cannot access variables in other javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js

The problem is that I try to put my codes in separate javascript files. And one file will refer to an variable in a file which is referenced in `index.html` file previously.

For instance, the two files in my public folder are `client.js` and `test.js`.

In my `client.js` file, I have these codes:

```
function init() {
    var socket = io.connect();
    var temp = x;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
```

In my `test.js` file, I have these codes:

```
var x = 5;
```

In my `index.html` file, I have these codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Amazing Particle System</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <canvas id="particle"></canvas>
      <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
      <script scr="/test.js"></script>
      <script src="/client.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

But when I run my code I always get the error:

> client.js:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

In developer tool I cannot see my `test.js` file in sources tab.

Is there anything I have done wrong in my code? How can I fix the issue?

Comment: where and how do you call the init function, have you considered passing x as a parameter when calling it?

Comment: @VladimirDrenovski I omit some codes for io connection. but this is the client side of a nodejs project so you get the idea. The `init` function is called in `client.js` as I said in the question.

Comment: You have to correct a typo in `<script scr="/test.js"></script>`, you have wrote `scr` instead of `src`attribute.. That's why your script do not work

Comment: @YosvelQuintero You have the correct answer, please post it as one.

Comment: @YosvelQuintero Oh yes thanks for pointing it out how stupid I was. The editor didn't tell me the typo so I have been scratching my head for the silly mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to correct a typo in `<script scr="/test.js"></script>`, you have wrote `scr` instead of `src` attribute.. That's why your script do not work as expected